# Strange behavior with RequireJS using CommonJS sintax

Tags: javascript, download, requirejs, commonjs

I'm a strange behavior with RequireJS using the CommonJS syntax. I'll try to explain as better as possible the context I'm working on.

I have a JS file, called `Controller.js`, that registers for input events (a click) and uses a series of `if` statement to perform the correct action. A typical if statement block can be the following.

```
if(something) {

    // RequireJS syntax here

} else if(other) { // ...
```

To implement the RequireJS syntax I tried two different patterns. The first one is the following. This is the standard way to load modules.

```
if(something) {
    require(['CompositeView'], function(CompositeView) {

        // using CompositeView here... 

    });

} else if(other) { // ...
```

The second, instead, uses the CommonJS syntax like

```
if(something) {
    var CompositeView = require('CompositeView');

    // using CompositeView here... 

} else if(other) { // ...
```

Both pattern works as expected but I've noticed a strange behavior through Firebug (the same happens with Chrome tool). In particular, using the second one, the `CompositeView` file is already downloaded even if I haven't follow the branch that manages the specific action in response to `something` condition. On the contrary, with the first solution the file is downloaded when requested.

Am I missing something? Is it due to variable hoisting?

Comment: It's not due to variable hoisting. I'd check to make sure that you're not explicitly importing that script some other way, because what you're describing really shouldn't happen.

Comment: @Pointy Thanks for your comment. I checked twice but not way to figure out the problem. Yes, hoisting is not the problem but I asked only for confirmation...

Comment: The [Tamper Data](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/tamper-data/) add-on for Firefox, or the native browser developer tools, usually can show you all the HTTP requests going on. You should clear your cache and verify that in the callback version (which really is the correct way to do things anyway) you're definitely not importing the script when your code takes the "else" branch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a limitation of the support for CommonJS-style `require`. The [documentation](http://requirejs.org/docs/whyamd.html#sugar) explains that something like this:

```
define(function (require) {
    var dependency1 = require('dependency1'),
        dependency2 = require('dependency2');

    return function () {};
});
```

is translated by RequireJS to:

```
define(['require', 'dependency1', 'dependency2'], function (require) {
    var dependency1 = require('dependency1'),
        dependency2 = require('dependency2');

    return function () {};
});
```

Note how the arguments to the 2 `require` calls become part of the array passed to `define`.

What you say you observed is consistent with RequireJS reaching inside the `if` and pulling the required module up to the `define` so that it is **always** loaded even if the branch is not taken. The only way to prevents RequireJS from always loading your module is what you've already discovered: you have to use `require` with a callback.

Comment: Thanks. You are correct. Based on source code, RequireJS will find that pattern at any level and will push the additional dependencies as you described (see `define` function at row *1984*).